# Too many initializers for symbol

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the MIT project [CryptoDB](https://github.com/henrysher/cryptoDB). I have downloaded it and I have followed the instructions to compile as it is explained in the included instructions, for mysql-proxy and mysql version 5.5.14. I am using a RedHat Enterprise 6 server.

When I get to the point of running the make command i get this error:

```
Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/sql_lex.cc.o
In file included from /soft/mysql-5.5.14/build/sql/lex_hash.h:25,
                 from /soft/mysql-5.5.14/sql/sql_lex.cc:113:
/soft/mysql-5.5.14/sql/lex.h:193: error: ‘ENC_SYM’ was not declared in this scope
/soft/mysql-5.5.14/sql/lex.h:623: error: too many initializers for ‘SYMBOL’
make[2]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/sql_lex.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am quite lost as I cannot find if there is a missing library or any kind of incompatbility on what I am using. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i have not finished installation now I now that the problem comes from not having the last version of the code. By getting it with the following command:

```
git clone -b public git://g.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb
```

I get to execute an instalation script in ruby that performs the work.

The script is not writen especifically for Redhat, so I am having some work adapting some commands (apt-get => yum).